# how can I improve WI-FI speed?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, speed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I speed up data transfer between local computers on a WiFi network?](https://superuser.com/questions/263588/how-can-i-speed-up-data-transfer-between-local-computers-on-a-wifi-network)

My question is similar to this:
[How can I speed up data transfer between local computers on a WiFi network?](https://superuser.com/questions/263588/how-can-i-speed-up-data-transfer-between-local-computers-on-a-wifi-network)

but I have N router (wrt160n v3) and can transfer only 7 Mbyte/sec on my local network with my Mac (it has AirPort Extreme, 802.11n also)
I read that N wi-fi can reach 300 Mbit/sec, but 150 Mbit/sec is reachable.
So how could I improve ?

Comment: I am pretty sure this is still a dup and all the usual Wi-Fi improvement techniques apply here: choose a less-crowded non-overlapping channel, turn off 40MHz (i.e. 300Mbps) in noisy environments, turn off 802.11b compatibility, switch to 5GHz if possible, move closer to the AP, keep away from 2.4GHz cordless phones/wireless mouses/bluetooth devices/microwave ovens

Comment: @bill you forgot running showers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That bandwidth available as supported by your router is shared among all computers in the area using the channel your access point/router is listening on.  If the router supports 150Mbps, for example, there is at most 150Mbps total available for all devices to try and claim.

This means that if you want to transfer between two devices on the same router, the best you can hope for is half of that, as one device will first send to your access point, and the access point must then re-send each packet from there to the intended device, and they have to share the available airtime.  And in fact it's even worse than that, as wireless technologies don't have a mechanism for perfect time sharing.  One device may try to transmit a packet while the another is still active, and force both devices to re-send for that packet. In networking terms, we say wireless cells are *unswitched* and *half-duplex*.  Other non-computer interference sources can make things even worse. Also, it runs in inverse proportion to your connection speed. If a single device has a weak signal such that it can only connect at 11Mbps instead of 150Mbps, and fills up that 11Mbps with data, it's using up all the potential 150Mbps of air time.

When all is said and done, you're lucky to even get 7Mbps on shared wireless connections, let alone 7MBps. If you really care about performance, go wired or go home.

Answer (score 1):

Now you have to understand the difference between connection speed and download speed.

Listen carefully, To check your approximate download or data transfer speed divide your connection speed by 8 .

(IEEE Standards):
For example For  802.11 wifi connection speed is 54 Mbps ,so you will get approximately 6.72 MBps download speed.

In case of LAN(Ethernet cable)Connection speed is 100 Mbps ,you will get 12.5 MBps approx.,

Now considering your question you have to purchase the Wifi Routers or adapters with specific high connection speed as your choice .