# Causes of slow network connection between two Windows 7 computers on LAN but either Win7 and a Linux computer are not slow

Tags: linux, windows, networking, wireless-networking, performance

I am experiencing slow (approx. 1 MB/s) transfer speeds on my home wireless network between two Windows 7 computers.  Speeds improve when switching to Ethernet on both.  This speed is being observed when transferring a file.  Internet speeds are fine 3-4 MB/s per SpeedTest.

If either of the two Windows 7 computers transfers the same file between a Linux computer that is also on the network, speeds are over 10 MB/s.

I've tried resetting my router Cisco/Linksys router to default settings, uninstalled and then reinstalled wireless drivers on both Windows 7 computers.  I'm looking for ideas/suggestions for troubleshooting or possibilities of causes.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I speed up data transfer between local computers on a WiFi network?](http://superuser.com/questions/263588/how-can-i-speed-up-data-transfer-between-local-computers-on-a-wifi-network)

Answer (score -2):

You are not specifying how you are transfering the files. From one side you can try to change the ethernet cables with new ones. You can call your ISP and order them to replace your router. You can update to windows 8.1.

Probably you're not using the same program to transfer the files between the two computers with windows and the two computers with linux and windows respectively. Try using scp on the command line in both computers and then compare.

Comment: What on earth updating to win8 has to do with this problem?

Comment: This is a question about wireless not ethernet.